# missing output from serialize with hashMap, YAML

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, yaml, snakeyaml

Hi I'm trying to learn how to use snakeYAML.

I want to save a **Library** object so I can load it again when I start my application.
Simply I want to store my library with books in it. Internet told me **yaml** was a good way to do this.

I have to following class:

```
public class Library {
private HashMap<String, List<Book>> library; 

public Library() {
    library = new HashMap<String, List<Book>>();
}

//getter
public HashMap<String, List<Book>> getHashMap() {
    return library;
}

//setter
public void setHashMap(HashMap<String, List<Book>> library) {
    this.library = library;
}
}
```

and now I want to serialize it using a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Library library = new Library();
    LinkedList<Book> books = new LinkedList<Book>();

    books.add(new Book("Some title", false));
    books.add(new Book("Other Title", true));

    library.putMany("books", books);

    System.out.println(new Yaml().dump(books));
```

but I only get the output:

```
- !!model.Book {done: false, title: Some title}
- !!model.Book {done: true, title: Other Title}
```

and something tells me I'm missing out on something like the **Library** itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That must be because you are only `dump()`ing the list of two `books`, not the entire `Library`.

Comment: Of course! Such a simple mistake! With that I have closure! Thanks!